# php mysql add sub array to main array

Tags: php, mysql

I need to append result of mysql query with existing result of another query, and both queries performed on different table, actually what I really want to do is take value from main table and get some data from another table using first value, and combine all together using json encode.

```
$query = "select ID,TIMESTAMP,UUID from  TABLE1 where USERNAME='$user'";
$result  = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if($numrows>0)
 {
   $res=$a;
   $myArray = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $eachuuid =  $row[UUID];
        $query1 = "select ID,IMAGEURL from  TABLE_IMAGES where IMG_UUID='$eachuuid'";
        $result1  = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
        $numrows1 = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($numrows1>0){
           $res1; 
           $myArray1 = array();
           while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
           $myArray1[] = $row1;
          }
          $row['IMG_URL']=$myArray1;
         }

      $myArray[] = $row;
   }

   $res['Data']=$myArray;
   echo json_encode($res);
```

Result:

```
{"Response":"OK","Data":[{"ID":"62",
                          "TIMESTAMP":"26 January",
                          "UUID":"12345",
                          "IMG_URL":[{"ID":"5","IMAGEURL":"26_January_2016_22_39_28_crop.jpg"}]}]}
```

And I need to get the output like,

```
{"Response":"OK","Data":[{"ID":"62",
                              "TIMESTAMP":"26 January",
                              "UUID":"12345",
                              "IMG_URL":{"ID":"5","IMAGEURL":"26_January_2016_22_39_28_crop.jpg"}}]}
```

Means need to remove [] from `IMG_URL` section so that I can parse the data easily.

Comment: Where is the value for $user coming from? If it's being submitted by the user it needs to be validated and a prepared statement used. For the second query, consider using IN for the WHERE clause instead of hitting the database multiple times. Is there a common field that could be used for a join?

Comment: The variable `$user` passed as an argument to the php while it's calling form client, and I didn't understand  Is there a common field that could be used for a join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
$row['IMG_URL']=$myArray1[0];
```

Or

```
  $myArray1 = null;
  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $myArray1 = $row1;
  }
  $row['IMG_URL']=$myArray1;
```

I hope this helps.